# How to read, validate and move a .csv file?

Tags: java, csv, file-handling

I am new to Java and I got a situation to which I'm clueless about. I need to take all the csv files from a folder read them one by one, validate them for eg. There's data like name, age, email etc. So the name should have only letters, age should be numeric and email should be in valid email format. The file which has invalid data in any of the row, there shouldn't be any further processing of that particular csv file and it should be moved to another folder which will have erroneous csv files and the program will move onto next csv in the folder until all of them gets checked, validated and moved. 
I don't know how to begin with this. Please help me out guys.

Comment: That is a lot to ask here.  Sorry.

Comment: Okay. How should I start with it at least? Like how do I parse the csv row by row and get data out of it for validation?

Comment: You could try looking at reading CSV files with the Apache utilities: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: The one real thing here: you start by putting terms such as "java reading csv" into your search engine. You might be surprised how much material you will find. And you study the [help] to understand how /what to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, save your file to `.csv` format1. This works on excel sheets. Then call this function in `main()` by this code, you will read the `.csv` file row-wise, each cell at a time .

Try this out:

```
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> convertCSVRecordToList() {

    String csvFile = "your_file_name.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    HashMap<String, Object> Map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    List<HashMap<String, Object>> MapList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line);

            String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);         

            Map.put("filed_name", data[3]);
            Map.put("field_name", data[0]);
            Map.put("field_name", data[2]);
            Map.put("fiels_name", data[1]);

            MapList.add(Map);
            Map = new HashMap<String, Object>();                
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return MapList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, let's separate this question into following four smaller topics:

1. Java program to read a folder, result is a list of files
2. Java program to read a file, result is a list of lines
3. Java program to parse a line, get a list of columns
4. For name, age, email, validate the data

Step 1: Java program to read a folder, result is a list of files

Assuming you have below in your top of java program

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```

Below code should get a list of file in a folder

```
File f = new File(folder);
File[] fileList = f.listFiles();
```

Step 2: Java program to read a file, result is a list of lines

```
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  String l = line.trim(); // Remove end of line. You can print line here.
}
br.close();
```

Step 3: Java program to parse a line, get a list of columns

```
String[] columns = l.split(",");  // separate line by comma
for( int i=0; i<columns.length; i++ )
{
    System.out.println(columns[i].trim());// remove space after comma
}
```

Step 4: Validate e.g. age
Age has to be integer so parse it as integer

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(columns[3].trim());//assuming age at column #3
```

See another answer come out. That answer doesn't have folder to file loop.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem here: if we are talking *real* csv files then your naive approach to parse them using split will break. Parsing csv is serious businesses and easy to get wrong.

Comment: He is a beginner, cannot show too many in the first round. By the time, he know more on C#, more details should follow.